# Determining boolean expression from truth table

Tags: logic, boolean-algebra

I have a truth table as follows

```
X Y Z A B C

0 0 0 0 0 1

0 0 1 0 1 0

0 1 0 1 0 1

0 1 1 1 0 0

1 0 0 0 1 1

1 0 1 1 0 0

1 1 0 1 0 1

1 1 1 1 1 0
```

where x, y and z are inputs and a, b and c are outputs. Normally, simplifying this into an expression would be easy with one output. I would just use k-maps and get the simplified Boolean expression from it. But with three outputs, I don't know how.

Comment: What are you trying to do with the outputs, are you trying to construct logic gates ?

Comment: I need to get the simplified boolean expression for the outputs so I can draw a circuit diagram

Comment: with 3 outputs you need 3 expressions.

Comment: So would I have to make 3 k-maps, one for each output?

Comment: yes or you can just take the dnf.

Comment: @asddf May I ask you what you call the dnf ?

Comment: disjunctive normal form, some people also call it sum of products i think

Comment: @asddf Thanks, I should have guessed.

Answer (score 2):

It's pretty clear by inspection that $c = \neg z$, so we can get that out of the way.

The simplest way I can see to specify $a$ is that $a = y \vee (x \wedge z)$. Again by inspection.

$b$ has no simple expression that I can see; you're not doing much better than just saying "x and not y and not z, or z and not y and not x, or x and y and z".